# Batch For loop exclude file name that contains

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file that will loop through all *Test.htm files and copy them.  Some of the files will contain a string that I don't want to copy.

```
FOR /R "C:\" %%g IN (*Test.htm) DO  (
echo %%g
)
```

What I want in pseudo code:

```
@echo off
FOR /R "C:\" %%g IN (*Test.htm) DO ( 
   if %%g contains "Exclude" do nothing
else 
   copy...
)
```

Comment: Do you mean that the file itself contains the string or that the filename contains the string?

Comment: Are you sure that you mean `*Test.htm` and not `*\Test.htm`   ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For filename:**

```
@echo off

FOR /R "C:\" %%g IN (*Test.htm) DO ( 
   (Echo "%%g" | FIND /I "Exclude" 1>NUL) || (
       Copy "%%g"...
   )
)
```

**For File content:**

```
@echo off

FOR /R "C:\" %%g IN (*Test.htm) DO ( 
   (Type "%%g" | FIND /I "Exclude" 1>NUL) || (
       Copy "%%g"...
   )
)
```

Comment: What is the 1 for ?

Comment: @DaveBoltman The index of the command's standard stream which to redirect to NULL. You can read more about at Wikipedia - the free encyclopedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams