# Excluding certain folders when scanning the contents of a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I'm using to scan the c:\users folders on a Windows 7 box using a for loop. This works fine, however I am having issues in excluding certain folders.

I need to exclude the AppData folder under the users profile folders. I don't want it to use a exclude file which I have seen in other solutions.

```
For /R C:\USERS\ %%G IN (*.png) do "C:\program files\sdelete\sdelete.exe\sdelete.exe" -s -p 3 /accepteula "%%G"
```

Comment: Post your batch file please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch For loop exclude file name that contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193702/batch-for-loop-exclude-file-name-that-contains)

Comment: ::For /R C:\USERS\ %%G IN (*.png) do  "C:\program files\sdelete\sdelete.exe\sdelete.exe" -s -p 3 /accepteula "%%G" is what I am using at the moment.  I would like to add in Gif PDF JPG extensions as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this: it should exclude `\appdata\` and `\folderb\`

```
For /R C:\USERS\ %%G IN (*.png *.gif *.pdf *.jpg) do (
    echo "%%G"|find /i "\appdata\" >nul || (echo "%%G"|find /i "\folderb\" >nul) || echo "%%~dpG" remove this after testing "C:\program files\sdelete\sdelete.exe\sdelete.exe" -s -p 3 /accepteula "%%G"
)
```

Comment: It redirects normal screen text to nowhere.  `Standard out` is normal screen text, and `standard error` is where error messages are sent.  They both go to the console by default and are known as streams 1 and 2 respectively.  You may also see terms like `2>nul` and `2>&1` to redirect error messages.