# How to prevent a batch file from renaming itself

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that's supposed to rename every file in a directory, but it keeps renaming itself and then won't continue with the script afterwards.

```
for /r %%b in (*) do (
    ren %%b !random!
)
```

The question could be a clone of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193702) but even after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797983) in combination with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193702), I still can't figure it out.

Either I'm dumb and the answer is really simple, or it's because I'm tired and I can't think straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's really what you want try:

```bat
For /R %%A In (*) Do If /I Not "%%A"=="%~f0" Ren "%%A" %RANDOM%
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) said worked, but I had to change `%0` to `%~f0` to get the full directory, filename and file extension.

Comment: You could have changed that to, `%~dpnx0` or as per my now edited answer.